# ERROR: Invalid index on empty tuple - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create a genereic AWS IAM role only when I run the code in us-west-2 region and don't want to use the same role when I run the same code in other region. Here is my terraform code:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "trino_s3_ssm_sync" {
  count = var.region == "us-west-2" ? 1 : 0
  name               = "trino-s3-ssm-sync"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.trust_ssm_sync[0].json
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "trino_s3_ssm_sync" {
  filename         = data.archive_file.trino_s3_ssm_sync.output_path
  function_name    = "trino-users-s3-ssm-sync"
  role             = aws_iam_role.trino_s3_ssm_sync[0].arn
  handler          = "trino-users-s3-ssm-sync.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.trino_s3_ssm_sync.output_base64sha256
  timeout          = 300
  runtime          = "python3.8"
  tags             = merge(local.common_tags)

  environment {
  }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Error: Invalid index
> │
> │   on ssm_sync_lambda.tf line 89, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "trino_s3_ssm_sync":
> │   89:   role             = aws_iam_role.trino_s3_ssm_sync[0].arn
> │     ├────────────────
> │     │ aws_iam_role.trino_s3_ssm_sync is empty tuple
> │
> │ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the
> │ collection has no elements.

Can you please help me resolve the above issue? I am new to Terraform

Comment: Please add any relevant code (the part of the code causing the error) to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `count` meta-argument in one resource, I would suggest using it in the second one, because if the first one does not get created and you try to reference it in the second one, terraform will produce the error you are getting. To fix this, you can try the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "trino_s3_ssm_sync" {
  count              = var.region == "us-west-2" ? 1 : 0
  name               = "trino-s3-ssm-sync"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.trust_ssm_sync[0].json
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "trino_s3_ssm_sync" {
  count            = var.region == "us-west-2" ? 1 : 0
  filename         = data.archive_file.trino_s3_ssm_sync.output_path
  function_name    = "trino-users-s3-ssm-sync"
  role             = aws_iam_role.trino_s3_ssm_sync[count.index].arn
  handler          = "trino-users-s3-ssm-sync.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.trino_s3_ssm_sync.output_base64sha256
  timeout          = 300
  runtime          = "python3.8"
  tags             = merge(local.common_tags)
  environment {
  }
}
```